Regex pattern match until the next occurence of the pattern
I'm trying to split a string using a regex pattern and including everything in between (could also be nothing) until the next occurrence of the pattern. However, the "everything in between" is matched with the next occurrence. So for example I have the following string:
content = """
/path/to/source.cpp:8:18: error: 'FOO' was not declared in this scope
    8 |     std::cout << FOO << std::endl;
      |                  ^~~
/path/to/source.cpp:9:18: error: 'BAR' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'EBADR'?
    9 |     std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
      |                  ^~~
      |                  EBADR
"""

and so far I came up with the following regex pattern containing the lookahead assertion to match the next time a path:line:col match is found in the string:
re_comp = re.compile((
      r"^((?P<path>.*?):(?P<line>[0-9]*):(?P<column>[0-9]*): )?"
      r"(?P<type>error|warning): "
      r".+?[\r\n]+(?=^.*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*|\Z)"
    ),
    re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

The problem is that with the current regex pattern, the message is assigned to the path group of the next finding, when I try to iterate over the findings:
for m in re_comp.finditer(content):
  print(m.group(0) 

will print
/path/to/source.cpp:8:18: error: 'FOO' was not declared in this scope

for the first iteration and
    8 |     std::cout << FOO << std::endl;
      |                  ^~~
/path/to/source.cpp:9:18: error: 'BAR' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'EBADR'?

for the second iteration.
Instead I would want to have one match finding each time a new path:line:col pattern starts. Such as
--------------------1st finding -----------------------------------
    /path/to/source.cpp:8:18: error: 'FOO' was not declared in this scope
        8 |     std::cout << FOO << std::endl;
          |                  ^~~
--------------------2nd finding -----------------------------------
    /path/to/source.cpp:9:18: error: 'BAR' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'EBADR'?
        9 |     std::cout << BAR << std::endl;
          |                  ^~~
          |                  EBADR

Can you help me fix my regex pattern?

You appear to be matching against some logs.  Can you highlight what the matched portions should be here?

@TimBiegeleisen Added some information at the bottom, hope it's sufficient

Because you use the DOTALL flag, this part of the regex .+?[\r\n]+(?=^.*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*|\Z) will match as few as possible characters (at least 1) where there is ::  colon to the right (because [0-9]* matches optional digits)
So the assertion is true because there is std::cout in the second line.
What you might do is match a newline and use [^\n]* in the lookahead to not match newlines, and assert at least a single digit :[0-9]+:[0-9]
^((?P<path>.*?):(?P<line>[0-9]*):(?P<column>[0-9]*): )?(?P<type>error|warning): .+?(?:[\r\n](?=[^\n]*:[0-9]+:[0-9])|\Z)

See a regex demo.

Another way to write the regex could be not using the DOTALL flag, but match all lines asserting that the next line does not have the :[0-9]+:[0-9] part using a negative lookahead
^((?P<path>.*?):(?P<line>[0-9]*):(?P<column>[0-9]*): )?(?P<type>error|warning): .+(?:\n(?!.*:[0-9]+:[0-9]).*)*

See another regex demo
